# Animate width to fit-content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I need to animate a `div` from a width of `0` (initial) to a width `fit-content` (a width that is the same as the width of its content)

```
$('div').css('width', 'fit-content');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yzugzf3h/1/)

However, if I do this the animation

```
transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
```

doesn't work anymore. So the question is how can I animate just to fit the content ?

UPDATE: I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css) ([DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yzugzf3h/5/)

Comment: grab the width in px of the parent and animate with px value instead of fit-content

Comment: I am not sure you can animate a value like that. Why not try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yzugzf3h/3/

Comment: In my case that doesn't work because multiple elements can be in the parent:  [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yzugzf3h/4/)

Comment: I found the solution and updated my post. Thank for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('div').css('width', $('div').find('span').width() + 'px');
}, 1000);
```

like this JSfiddle:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzugzf3h/6/)

Comment: There are a  few ways this could be enhanced, like switching to the actual fit-content value once the animation completes, or restarting the animation if something in the window is resized. Those might not always be necessary, though.